# Como abrir link externo fora do app?

Tags: java, android

Meu projeto simplesmente abre a pagina de meu blog, e lá tem vários links de outros sites com domínio diferente do meu. Quero que sempre que o usuário clicar em um desses links, o mesmo abra no navegador do usuário sem que abra no app. App baseado em `WebView`

Aqui esta meu código Java

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView navegador;

    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        navegador = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.SAIT);
        navegador.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        navegador.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);


        navegador.loadUrl("https://www.exemplo.com");
    }

}
```

Comment: por favor me ajudem